# Simultaneously update text area while typing in text field

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jtextarea

I want to update my text area along with typing in the text field but i get a delay of 1 keystroke while typing i.e when i press a key the previous key is displayed.Here is my snippet

```
private void jTextField1KeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt)
{         
    String a = jTextField1.getText();
    jTextArea1.setText(a);            
}
```

Comment: You change the accepted answer more often than the wind changes its direction.

Comment: @Dan actually i wanted to accept both the answers but couldn't so now finally i stick to 1.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would not recommend using `KeyListeners`

Simply add a `DocumentListener` to your `JTextField` via:

```
textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
            }
        });
```

Inside each of the methods ( `insertUpdate`,`removeUpdate` and `changedUpdate`) simply put in a call to set the text of your `JTextArea` via `setText()`:

```
textArea.setText(textField.getText());
```

Here is an example I made:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test().createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createAndShowUI() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        initComponents(frame);

        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initComponents(JFrame frame) {
        final JTextField jtf = new JTextField(20);
        final JTextArea ta = new JTextArea(20,20);

        ta.setEditable(false);

        jtf.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
                ta.setText(jtf.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
                ta.setText(jtf.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
            //Plain text components don't fire these events.
            }
        });

        frame.getContentPane().add(jtf, BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.getContentPane().add(ta, BorderLayout.EAST);
    }
}
```

Comment: ya it works fine.But what way is it different from that posted above or has more advantage.

Comment: @HarshitSharaff The main advantage is `KeyListener` won't work if you paste in or cut text, where as a `DocumentListener` will.

Answer (score 6):

You should do that under the `keyReleased` event instead of the `keyTyped` and it will work as you need.

Comment: I agree that, that will solve his problem, but he may also want a loop to begin once the key is pressed in case it is held down. You may just need a loop with a short wait() or sleep() in it

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait till the event on your TextField is processed before updating the TextArea. Your code update the TextArea before the TextField is done processing the new typed character. Hence the text set in the TextArea is one keystroke behind.

Comment: no its not the case.No matter how much i wait it does not update untill the next keystroke

Comment: Because it's the event you're working with, it doesn't matter in term of time. Dan's answer is exactly what I had in mind, the event of making the keystroke update the TextField is processed at the time keyReleased is called.

Comment: got it what you were trying to say

Answer (score 0):

You could try using recursion by referencing the method inside the method (avoid loops though).