# How to change the value of the JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, documentlistener

I am trying to built a Java application using `JFrame` with Swing, and I have 5 `JTextField` instances in there. One of these is for Sum.

I need `JTextField` to change automatically as soon as I type some number in text fields.

How is that possible?

What I wrote is here.

```
private void displaytotalActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
// display total:
Float num1,num2,num3,num4,num5,num6,result;
num1 = display1b.getText().equals("") ? 0 : Float.parseFloat(display1b.getText());
num2 = display2b.getText().equals("") ? 0 : Float.parseFloat(display2b.getText());
num3 = display3b.getText().equals("") ? 0 : Float.parseFloat(display3b.getText());
num4 = display4b.getText().equals("") ? 0 : Float.parseFloat(display4b.getText());
num5 = display5b.getText().equals("") ? 0 : Float.parseFloat(display5b.getText());
num6 = display6b.getText().equals("") ? 0 : Float.parseFloat(display6b.getText());

result = num1+num2+num3+num4+num5+num6;

System.out.println(result);
}
```

I tried to get the sum and display it in this textfield using button and it worked. But i want it to be done automatically. But the code above doesnt display anything on textfield.

I am quite new to this and I appreciate if you kindly guide.

Comment: What have you tried? Stackoverflow isn't going to write your crappy code for you.

Comment: Which part of it are you having a problem with - detecting data entry, parsing the text to a number, adding the numbers?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of current code (but note it only needs 3 text fields - 2 for entry and one for result).  BTW - are the numbers integers?

Comment: *"I appreciate if you kindly guide"*  That is an odd thing to write, given you have ignored my advice to post an SSCCE.  A good way to express appreciation is to listen carefully and follow advice.  Note that if an `ActionListener` is aded to the input text fields, and the user presses `Enter` when one of those text fields is in focus, the listener will be activated.  You might also look into [`DocumentListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html).

Answer (score 7):

I think you're looking for

- the [`setText()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setText(java.lang.String)) method of a `JTextField`.
- [Writing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) a [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html) to know when the text changes and apply sum to it
- [Writing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) a [DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DocumentFilter.html) to make sure your program does not crash with input different to numbers.

An alternative to this is to use a [JFormattedTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html) and using listeners.

A couple of recommendations.

- Develop intuition, usually properties to java classes are changed by `(get|set)Property`. Use an IDE like Netbeans and it will help you finding stuff.
- Automatization is usually achieved by using a Listener, just learn when to use which (this is also part of intuition).
- When you find yourself writing repeated code, consider using a function. i.e.

Instead of having 6 times:

```
display1b.getText().equals("") ? 0 : Float.parseFloat(display1b.getText());
```

Consider having your fields in an `ArrayList` and write a function that iterates them and have a single line of the above to set all the values.

- Follow the [JavaTutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) before additional efforts of hard-coding, or asking here. Will be more productive to you. Because you will learn how to learn for yourself and dig into documentation.

Comment: You are right, but it's not what the OP is looking for - *"I need JTextField to change automatically as soon as I type some number in text fields"* would be the part of the question I'd be focusing on.  If you have some ideas about how to achieve this, then please update your answer :D

Comment: @MadProgrammer What for? instead of guide, you provided a full coded answer.

Comment: Because you might have a better idea, or solution (and I really don't want to see your answer draw any down votes)

Comment: See +1 nice use of JFormattedTextField!

Answer (score 6):

You need to use a `DocumentListener` attached to each of the number fields.  This will alert you when the fields have changed.

From there you need to call some sort of `sum` method to automatically update the tally.

Something like...

```
public class AutoSum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AutoSum();
    }

    public AutoSum() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new AutoSumPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class AutoSumPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextField[] fields;
        private JTextField tally;

        public AutoSumPane() {

            fields = new JTextField[5];

            DocumentListener docHandler = new DocumentListener() {
                @Override
                public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    autoSum();
                }

                @Override
                public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    autoSum();
                }

                @Override
                public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    autoSum();
                }
            };

            setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 1));
            for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
                fields[index] = new JTextField(3);
                fields[index].getDocument().addDocumentListener(docHandler);
                fields[index].setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
                add(fields[index]);
            }

            tally = new JTextField(3);
            tally.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
            tally.setEditable(false);

            add(tally);

        }

        protected float getValue(JTextField field) {
            float value = 0;
            String text = field.getText();
            if (text != null && text.trim().length() > 0) {
                try {
                    value = Float.parseFloat(text.trim());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return value;
        }

        protected void autoSum() {
            float sum = 0;
            for (JTextField field : fields) {
                sum += getValue(field);
            }
            tally.setText(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(sum));
        }
    }
}
```

for example.

Take a look at [How to Write a DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for more information.

While you're at it, you might find [Implementing a DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) of interest (and [this](http://www.jroller.com/dpmihai/entry/documentfilter) for some examples)

Comment: Thanks alot MadProgrammer. Now I know DocumentListener is the thing i need to learn .

Comment: +1 nice mad. also see this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677638/simultaneously-update-text-area-while-typing-in-text-field/12678020#12678020) and this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174776/how-to-auto-calculate-input-numeric-values-of-text-field-in-java/14174868#14174868) (the last examples shows how to use document filter to calculate sums on the fly and setText accordingly of JTextField)

Comment: @david you just like me up voting your answers ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer hahaha it has its perks :). but more so you have answered the question so posting a duplicate solution is useless (and un-moral), where as now OP can see the way to go and some other examples too

Comment: @MadProgrammer : Seems to me, instead of providing external links, you could have provided the links to your own answers, which in my opinion are way too good. I do remember some of your previous answers related to DocumentListener, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @GagandeepBali that's a good point, but this demonstrates a possible solution using the OPs question

Comment: @MadProgrammer : As to why I said that, I totally liked this approach, far better than what I could have thought :-). Though it is missing, just one thingy, which is to check for the Integer input for the `JTextField`, so that the OP too can understand the benefits of the same.

Comment: @GagandeepBali Fair point - I was encouraging the OP to read the docs on `DocumentFilter` and the `Float.parseFloat` is wrapped in an exception handler to short circuit possible issues - but a fair point