# Unable to update TextArea while typing in Text Field at same time

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, documentlistener

Hello guyz i am new to java swing and working on a project, I am unable to update the text which i was typed in text field to text area in java swing , I am using this [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677638/simultaneously-update-text-area-while-typing-in-text-field) as a reference , but i am making my GUI using Drag and Drop in Netbeans by using JFrame Form

Here is my code

```
private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:

      String s = this.jTextField1.getText();
      jTextArea1.setEditable(false);

        jTextField1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
                jTextArea1.setText(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
                jTextArea1.setText(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
            //Plain text components don't fire these events.
            }
        });

    }
```

I am unable to do this by using Drag and drop method , whereas its working fine for me as like example which i have posted above.

Any help would be highly appreciate

Comment: It is unlikely that you meant to add the document listener in an action listener. Simply add the document listener somewhere where you setup the GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, we don't put a Listener inside another Listener, which makes the inner Listener to be called multiple times. 
Clear out the following code.

```
jTextArea1.setEditable(false);

jTextField1.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
        jTextArea1.setText(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
        jTextArea1.setText(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent de) {
        //Plain text components don't fire these events.
    }
});
```

Then use your Netbeans GUI Builder to make the jTextArea1 non-editable ( in the Properties ) and also add a DocumentListener to the jTextField1 like what you did with its ActionListener.

Then update the text in the newly added methods created by the GUI Builder, which I believed to be:

```
public void jTextField1RemoveUpdate(DocumentEvent de)
public void jTextField1InsertUpdate(DocumentEvent de)
```

in each method, you make a call to jTextArea1.setText(jTextField1.getText());

Comment: Well it helps me to clear my concept that we can't use listener inside any another listener , i tried to copy paste my code in the constructor of my GUI from my action listener of my textbox and it worked , Thanks Mate :)